# ActiveMQ client jar source code

Tags: client, activemq-classic, src

Where do I find the source code for the following jar file?

activemq-core-5.6.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveMQ source is located in SVN repo at Apache. You can check out the project using the following command.

> svn co https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/trunk activemq

The source jars are also stored in the Maven repo for the release in question, the core source jar is [here](https://repository.apache.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=releases&g=org.apache.activemq&a=activemq-core&v=5.6.0&e=jar&c=sources):